# Can an Azure SQL server be unavailable / unreachable for a period of time after creation?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-sql-server, azure-pipelines-yaml, invoke-sqlcmd

I am creating an Azure SQL server & db via a terraform task within an Azure Devops Pipeline using hosted agents.

The resources create without issue.

However, the next job in my stage tries to run a db_init.sql script against the newly created db using the [Azure SQL Database Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment?view=azure-devops). This task will fail intermittently with the following error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "**[redacted]**.database.windows.net" -Database "**[redacted]**" -Username "**[redacted]**"  -Password ******  -Inputfile "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6F48.tmp"  -ConnectionTimeout 120
>
> ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: No resource found with serverName **[redacted]**, serverType Microsoft.Sql/servers
> in subscription **[redacted]**. Specify the correct serverName/serverType and
> try again.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at
> https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-

The troubleshooting link above has not been useful.
I have also found this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370013/azuredevops-azure-sql-server-deployment-problems-and-solution) but the answer there is not applicable.

The pipeline setup is as follows:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: rg
  displayName: Create Resource Group
  ...

- stage: db
  dependsOn: 
    - rg
  displayName: Create DB Stage

  jobs:
    - job: createDB
      displayName: 'Create Database'

      steps:
        
         ...

       - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
         name: terraformApply
         displayName: Terraform Apply
         inputs: ...

       - task: PowerShell@2
         displayName: Read terraform outputs
         name: terraformOutput
         inputs:
           pwsh: true
           targetType: 'inline'
           script: |
               $terraformOutput = Get-Content "$(terraformApply.jsonOutputVariablesPath)" | ConvertFrom-Json
               $terraformOutput | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % { $o = $terraformOutput.($_.Name); Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($_.Name);isoutput=true;issecret=$($o.sensitive)]$($o.value)" }
           failOnStderr: true
           showWarnings: true

    - job:
      displayName: Initialise DB
      dependsOn: createDB
      variables:
        serverFQDN: $[ dependencies.createDB.outputs['terraformOutput.sql_server_fqdn'] ] 
        dbName: $[ dependencies.createDB.outputs['terraformOutput.sql_db_name'] ] 
        serverName: $[ dependencies.createDB.outputs['terraformOutput.server_name'] ]
      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      steps:
        - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
          displayName: Initialise DB
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: '[azure subscription id]'
            AuthenticationType: 'server'
            ServerName: '$(serverFQDN)'
            DatabaseName: '$(dbName)'
            SqlUsername: '[sql admin username]'
            SqlPassword: '[sql admin password]'
            deployType: 'SqlTask'
            SqlFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/[path-to]/db_init.sql'
            IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```

The issue is infrequent and the pipeline often succeeds after retrying the failed step. However, I have occasionally seen the 'Initialise DB' step fail 3 or 4 retries in a row over a period of several minutes.

I have also tested using an Azure CLI task to wait for the db server (testing both --created & --exists flags) before attempting to initialise but this does not seem to help.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Wait for DB to be ready'
  inputs:
     azureSubscription: '$(azure-subscription-id)'
     scriptType: bash
     scriptLocation: inlineScript
     inlineScript: |
         # wait up to 5 minutes for the db server to be available. check every 10 seconds
         az sql server wait --exists --interval 10 --timeout 300 --resource-group [rg name] --name $(serverName)
     failOnStderr: true
```

EDIT 2021-03-05: On deeper investigation this issue seems to be caused by a problem with an Azure API call used by the pipeline task.
In order to set the firewall rule, the task attempts to retrieve the id of the target Azure Sql server. To do so, it calls `GET https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/[subscription id]/resources?api-version=2014-04-01` and loops through the response to find a Sql server resource with a matching name.
On some occasions I have seen this action fail >30 mins after the db server has been created, while I have been able to query it within the Azure portal.

Comment: Here is a [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/firewall-auto-detect-failure-for-sqlserver-failove/584081) with the same error you can refer to.

Comment: @Hi-Guy, thanks I had come across that already but the firewall setting doesn't seem like the root cause as we never set it to 'Allow' and the task works most of the time.

Comment: @Killian We are glad to see you have found the root cause! It should be posted as answer not only the the new edit. I just help you post that.  You can think about accept it as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members. You also could post by your self certainly, then I will delete mine. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Killian, We are glad to see you have found the root cause. It should be posted as answer and I just help you post it. You can think about accept it as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members. You also could post it by your self certainly, then I will delete mine. Thank you for you sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are glad to see you have found the root cause! We could learn from you new edit:

**EDIT 2021-03-05:**

- On deeper investigation this issue seems to be caused by a problem
  with an Azure API call used by the pipeline task. In order to set the
  firewall rule, the task attempts to retrieve the id of the target
  Azure Sql server. To do so, it calls `GET https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/[subscription id]/resources?api-version=2014-04-01` and loops through the response
  to find a Sql server resource with a matching name. On some occasions
  I have seen this action fail >30 mins after the db server has been
  created, while I have been able to query it within the Azure portal.

I Help you post it as answer and this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you for you sharing!